# db.SaveChanges does not save changes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

Can somebody help me out with `db.SaveChanges`? It is not saving changes made to an object. I have added project model.

```
public class Project
    {
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }        
        public String Name { get; set; }    
        public virtual ICollection<ProjectParam> ProjectParams { get; set; }       
    }    



// Project object
Project project = new Project { Name = ProjectName, ProjectID = ProjectID };
project.ProjectParams = new List<ProjectParam>();

// Update all params
for (int i = 0; i < ParamIDs.Length; i++)            
    project.ProjectParams.Add(new ProjectParam { ParamID = Convert.ToInt32(ParamIDs[i]), 
                                                 ParamValue = ParamValues[i],
                                                 ProjectID = ProjectID });

// Save changes
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    db.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;                               
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Comment: `ModelState.IsValid` is `true` and `db.SaveChanges();` is definitely being called?

Comment: Spender thank you for your comment, I put a break point inside. Yes, code inside ModelState.IsValid is being called.

Answer (score 2):

Before you set the Entry.State and call SaveChanges(), attach the project to your Project entity like so:

```
db.Projects.Attach(project);
db.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;                               
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: No. Setting state to `Modified` is enough. It also attaches the object. Please remove this answer, it only brings confusion.

Comment: @GertArnold: since it's a brand new object, the state probably should be set to `Added` - not `Modified` ....

Comment: @marc_s not necessarily. This is a valid way to update an existing object.

Comment: @GertArnold: OK - true enough - but to me, in this case (updating an existing object), it would seem a lot easier to just **fetch** that object from the context first, modify some properties, and save it. This seems a bit "sideways" - creating  a new object to "mimic" an existing one and then tweaking it..... anyways - but you're right - setting the `.State` to modified does in fact attach the object to the context

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments. I am still working on this. I will update this thread as soon as i find the root cause.  I am going to try the sideways marc_s suggested.

Comment: marc_s, I have added project model in the question and i tried your suggestion. It seems working for project name. But when i try to add new ProjectParam collection. It throws me error. "Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.ProjectParams'. The duplicate key value is (2, 1).". I could not find way to update already attached collection because it does not have indexer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did to resolve this. This seems working fine. Thanks everyone for your time.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int ProjectID,string ProjectName,string[] ParamIDs,string[] ParamValues)
        {
            // Get project from context
            Project project = db.Projects.Where(e => e.ProjectID == ProjectID).SingleOrDefault();
            project.Name = "Hi";

            // Remove existing parameters
            db.ProjectParams.RemoveRange(db.ProjectParams.Where(c => c.ProjectID == ProjectID));

            // Add new list of parameters
            project.ProjectParams= new List<ProjectParam>();

            //// Update all params
             for (int i=0;i< ParamIDs.Length;i++)
                project.ProjectParams.Add(new ProjectParam { ParamID = Convert.ToInt32(ParamIDs[i]),ParamValue=ParamValues[i],ProjectID=ProjectID });

            // Save changes
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(project).State = EntityState.Modified;                               
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");            
        }
```